# filter outgoing requests in node.js for logging

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building an Express app which on certain requests has to make its own HTTP calls. I could use Superagent, request or node's own `http.request`.
Thing is, I need to log all of those server originating requests and their respective responses. Calling `log.info` before each and every of those seems silly.

How can you add a pre-filter for all outgoing HTTP calls, and ideally access both `req` and `res`?

**NOTE:** I am not interested in logging requests coming in to the server I am building, only in the requests that the server itself kicks off. Think of my server as a client to another black box server.

Comment: You might want to decide first what library you use for your outgoing requests, and then see how you can log those. What do you want to log, just the headers? Or also full request bodies?

Comment: I've been trying with request. There's https://github.com/request/request-debug, but seeing the implementation made me cringe a little.
In Superagent and plain node APIs I didn't find any obvious places to hook into.

I would like to log the request method and URL, and the response status and time.

Comment: I'm trying something right now, if it works I'll post it as the answer.

Comment: Added a way to do so by proxying `http.request`. Otherwise you could also write your own request method that would be a wrapper around `http.request` or any other request library and that would handle the logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is patch http and https and proxy the `request` method. This way you can have a global handler that will catch the req & res objects.

```
var http    = require('http');
var https   = require('https');

var patch = function(object) {
    var original = object.request;

    // We proxy the request method
    object.request = function(options, callback) {
        // And we also proxy the callback to get res
        var newCallback = function() {
            var res = arguments[0];

            // You can log res here
            console.log("RES",res.statusCode);

            callback.apply(this,arguments);
        }

        var req = original(options, newCallback);

        // You can log your req object here.
        console.log(req.method,req.path);

        return req;
    }
}

patch(http);
patch(https);

http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response");
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Edit: This might work if you use the `request` npm package as well, as it might just rely on the built-in node.js `http.request` method anyways.

Comment: Thanks! That's a way to do it. Only downside is, you're going way down, and log everything relying on node's http, not necessarily just your application's calls.

Comment: Yeah, there are multiple ways to do it, better would be to write down your own class that would be an additional abstraction layer and log it there, so that you're not dependent on the underlying implementation.

Comment: The dream would be for libraries to implement a pre-filter callback. I'll go and ping either of Superagent or request. In the meantime, your answer totally answers the question. Thanks!

NOTE: unfortunately, _probably_ request does stuff to res and req, and when logging with Bunyan and its standard serializers, the output to stdout gets out of hand and the machine runs out of memory.

Comment: Yeah, just open an issue on their Github if they do not have one already. Request **does** add things to req and res, but if you use the piece of code I gave you you will access the object before they're modified by `request` so it should still be the same. Also, don't serialize the whole object, you should just log the interesting properties of the object like status code, path, relevant headers, etc. Glad my answer was useful to you!

Comment: I'm on board with that. Unfortunately, this line in Bunyan standard serializers makes the thing try to serialize the WHOLE request object: https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/blob/master/lib/bunyan.js#L1007
That's because there's no connection object on the request

Comment: I created my own class that takes the original request function as constructor argument. In that way I could override or proxy what I wanted. In my case I needed to add authorization header to all outgoing requests.

Answer (score 0):

What server are you going to use for you app? 
I would definally bring up such functionality on to server level. Take a look how heroku router is doing it. You can track all of needed information using some of their addons: papertrail, or newrelic ( or use them separately for you app ).

https://papertrailapp.com/

http://newrelic.com/

I like out-of-box solutions in this case, no need extend your app logic for logging such information.

If you want to have your own solution, you can setup nginx to monitor request/response info.
http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/

Comment: Read the question again, he wants to log **outgoing request** that his app makes, not incoming requests. He wants a catch-all that can logs all the HTTP requests it makes, not the ones it receives.

Comment: both of this services can track outbound traffic easily.

Comment: But it's not what he's asking for. He's asking for a way to, inside his application, catch all HTTP requests and log only some, adding his own layer of filtering if needed.

Comment: I wouldn't bring logging inside application, no matter what, just an my opinion ( if the logging is the final goal ).
Otherwise I'm agree with your solution.